# .NET 2.0 IL Optimization for a while loop

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, optimization

I've been reading a book `Pro Asynchronous Programming With .NET` and one of the first code examples demonstrates an optimization that the compiler makes on .NET 2.0 Framework when a thread an a loop is involved.

The code is the following:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AsyncSygnal h = new AsyncSygnal();
        while (!h.Terminate) ;
    }

    class AsyncSygnal
    {
        public bool Terminate;

        public AsyncSygnal()
        {
            Thread monitorThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(MonitorNetwork));
            monitorThread.Start();
        }

        private void MonitorNetwork()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            Terminate = true;
        }
    }
}
```

In the book it states that the JIT compiler on the `release` build moves the check out-side of the while loop. It works fine for the `debug` buid

How can that make sense?

IL for debug:

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       24 (0x18)
  .maxstack  2
  .locals init ([0] class Program/AsyncSygnal h,
           [1] bool V_1)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  newobj     instance void Program/AsyncSygnal::.ctor()
  IL_0006:  stloc.0
  IL_0007:  br.s       IL_000a
  IL_0009:  nop
  IL_000a:  ldloc.0
  IL_000b:  ldfld      bool Program/AsyncSygnal::Terminate
  IL_0010:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0011:  ceq
  IL_0013:  stloc.1
  IL_0014:  ldloc.1
  IL_0015:  brtrue.s   IL_0009
  IL_0017:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

IL for release:

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       15 (0xf)
  .maxstack  1
  .locals init ([0] class Program/AsyncSygnal h)
  IL_0000:  newobj     instance void Program/AsyncSygnal::.ctor()
  IL_0005:  stloc.0
  IL_0006:  ldloc.0
  IL_0007:  ldfld      bool Program/AsyncSygnal::Terminate
  IL_000c:  brfalse.s  IL_0006
  IL_000e:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

I guess what i'm really getting at is that i'm trying to understand the IL that's outputted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a slightly simpler example (from [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/2886#issuecomment-542734773)):

```
using System;
public abstract class C
{
    public abstract void WithAction(Action a);

    private bool creating = true;

    public void M()
    {
        WithAction(() => creating = false);

        while (creating) {}
    }
}
```

The IL for the `M()` method is pretty unremarkable.

Debug:

```
IL_0000: nop
// Call the WithAction method - I won't go into this
IL_0001: ldarg.0
IL_0002: ldarg.0
IL_0003: ldftn instance void C::'<M>b__2_0'()
IL_0009: newobj instance void [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Action::.ctor(object, native int)
IL_000e: callvirt instance void C::WithAction(class [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Action)
IL_0013: nop
IL_0014: br.s IL_0018
// loop start (head: IL_0018)
    IL_0016: nop
    IL_0017: nop
    // Load 'this.creating'
    IL_0018: ldarg.0
    IL_0019: ldfld bool C::creating
    // Store the value of 'this.creating' into local slot 0
    IL_001e: stloc.0
    // Load it back out of local slot 0
    IL_001f: ldloc.0
    // If it's true, go back to IL_0016
    IL_0020: brtrue.s IL_0016
// end loop

IL_0022: ret
```

Release:

```
// Call the WithAction method - I won't go into this
IL_0000: ldarg.0
IL_0001: ldarg.0
IL_0002: ldftn instance void C::'<M>b__2_0'()
IL_0008: newobj instance void [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Action::.ctor(object, native int)
IL_000d: callvirt instance void C::WithAction(class [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Action)
// loop start (head: IL_0012)
    // Load the value of 'this.creating' onto the stack
    IL_0012: ldarg.0
    IL_0013: ldfld bool C::creating
    // If it's true, go back to IL_0012
    IL_0018: brtrue.s IL_0012
// end loop
IL_001a: ret
```

(Annotations mainly by me)

As you can see, they're pretty much the same, except that the debug version has lots of `nops` (mainly so you can put breakpoints everywhere you'd want to), and it loads everything into local slots (mainly so you can look at them in the debugger).

However, once the JIT gets to them, they tell a different story. Just looking at the loop, in Debug:

```
L0052: nop
L0053: nop
L0054: mov eax, [ebp-0x4]
L0057: movzx eax, byte [eax+0x4]
L005b: mov [ebp-0x8], eax
L005e: cmp dword [ebp-0x8], 0x0
L0062: jnz L0052
```

Release:

```
L002f: movzx ecx, byte [esi+0x4]
L0033: test ecx, ecx
L0035: jnz L0033
```

You can see that the Debug version loads the value of `this.creating` on every loop iteration. The Release version however loads it once at L002f, and then never again - on each loop iteration it just does `test ecx, ecx`, never updating the value held in `ecx`.

---

This "makes sense" because if you're accessing a shared field (without any synchronization), the compiler and runtime are allowed to assume that the current thread is the only one accessing it. There are lots of optimizations which can be done because of this assumption: multiple consecutive reads can be condensed into a single read; same with writes; redundant reads or writes can be removed entirely, among others.

For example:

```
this.field = 1;
this.field = 2;
this.field = 3;
```

is indistinguishable (from the current thread's point of view) from:

```
this.field = 3;
```

The same logic applies to reading a field in a loop: if the current thread isn't writing to that field, the compiler and runtime are allowed to assume that nothing is.

More formally, this is written [in the spec](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/basic-concepts.md#execution-order):

> ### Execution order
>
> Execution of a C# program proceeds such that the side effects of each executing thread are preserved at critical execution points. A ***side effect*** is defined as a read or write of a volatile field, a write to a non-volatile variable, a write to an external resource, and the throwing of an exception. The critical execution points at which the order of these side effects must be preserved are references to volatile fields ([Volatile fields](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/classes.md#volatile-fields)), `lock` statements ([The lock statement](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/statements.md#the-lock-statement)), and thread creation and termination. The execution environment is free to change the order of execution of a C# program, subject to the following constraints:
>
> - Data dependence is preserved within a thread of execution. That is, the value of each variable is computed as if all statements in the thread were executed in original program order.
> - Initialization ordering rules are preserved ([Field initialization](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/classes.md#field-initialization) and [Variable initializers](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/classes.md#variable-initializers)).
> - The ordering of side effects is preserved with respect to volatile reads and writes ([Volatile fields](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/classes.md#volatile-fields)). Additionally, the execution environment need not evaluate part of an expression if it can deduce that that expression's value is not used and that no needed side effects are produced (including any caused by calling a method or accessing a volatile field). When program execution is interrupted by an asynchronous event (such as an exception thrown by another thread), it is not guaranteed that the observable side effects are visible in the original program order.

If you're accessing a field which another thread is also accessing, you *always* need some sort of synchronization. This could be a `lock` statement, or it could be something else (such as one of the methods on the `Interlocked` class).

---

You can play with all of the code here [on SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LghgzgtgNAJiA1AHwATtQAQEwEYCwAUBlgMypgBGEwATmAMbBbaoDCRJA3pyRpuSo16TLABZUAdQCWwABaZc2ABSLWYAJQBuIrz6oADrWkA3MMACmqSgHsbAG1QNaF89IB2Ac1QBeVHQBXCx1CPT4BcVQAWWUNMO54/SlZBSVlWN8APicXNy9fVAAzMHsIC21dYiSSAHc5aXsrZWdXYA9PDVQuAF9E9F6q/qA=) - use the ComboBoxes in the top right to change between IL and JIT Asm, and Debug/Release.

Let me know if you want me to go into the IL in more detail.